Literature Recommendation about Applied Probability Theory
I am taking a graduate course in probability theory and right now we spent over a month discussing random variables, their convergence type (almost sure, convergence in probability and $L^p$ convergence) and its conseqences. This is supposed to be an applied math course but I have no idea how this would be useful in the "real world". So I'm asking if there are any good books which illustrate with "real world" examples the actual applications of probability theory.

You have all my sympathies but there is no simple answer as probability theory is a vast subject and its applications even more. Personally I found it refreshing to get into mathematical finance and having to calculate lots of expected values either in closed form, by Monte Carlo or by using trees or PDEs. Elementary probability should also not be underestimated. As we can see from the Monty Hall media furor. What direction are you mostly interested?

After my studies I would actually like to pursue a career in mathematical finance or ensurance math.

In that case you might like the books and articles by Paul Wilmott for example who addresses a readership of young students who want to learn how to do the practical work. He is not the only such author. The finance industry would have gone nowhere when only that boring stuff is taught that you described.
